# Apache Giraph: Read in postgres rows as vertices?

Tags: postgresql, hadoop, giraph

Is it possible to read in rows from a sql database as vertices in apache giraph? If so, could someone provide a small code example? Thanks.

Comment: See my answer here perhaps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62419659/443593. You can export SQL to CSV or TSV and load into Giraph using TextEdgeInputFormat.